# Removendo items de um ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um `ComboBox` *Status* que busca aproxidamente 13 status de uma tabela:

```
cboStatus.DisplayMember = "nome";
cboStatus.ValueMember = "codigo";
cboStatus.DataSource = CartoesVTBLL.Status();
cboStatus.SelectedValue = "";
```

Nessa tabela eu tenho o campo *Restrição* que possui o *código* desses status. Porém, essa *Restrição* é para mostrar, ou seja, quando o `ComboBox` estiver no código *A* e na tabela possui Restrição "O;C;D" eu vou mostrar somente para alterar os status de O,C e D. Basicamente eu vou remover tudo o que for diferente desses status, sei que vou usar o split para separar os códigos mas como eu posso chegar nessa regra,  talvez um

```
remove.items.where(x => x.codigo != status.codigo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Como você está atribuindo um `DataSource` para a `ComboBox`, não é possível manipular sua coleção de itens manualmente.

Para o seu caso, é só fazer como você imaginou:

```
cboStatus.DataSource = CartoesVTBLL.Status().Where(x => x.codigo != status.codigo);
```

Comment: É esse seria um ponto que eu queria chegar, infelizmente não deu muito certo mas obrigado mesmo assim!

Comment: Por que não deu certo?

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia adicionar estes valores dentro de uma lista.

```
List<String> lista = new List<String>();
```

E remover o valor indesejado

```
var itemToRemove = resultlist.Single(r => r.item == "O"); // ou os valores que deseja
lista.Remove(itemToRemove);
```

Após isso você limpa seu ComboBox

```
cmbBox.Items.Clear();
```

E adiciona dentro do combobox os valores que sobraram na lista.

Comment: Um pouco confuso, mas obrigado mesmo assim!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui chegar ao resultado que eu queria, mas acho que deve haver uma maneira bem mais simplificada, em todo caso obrigado aos 2 pela resposta.

```
 string[] Array_Restricao = new string[13];               

                List<Cartao_Status> Lista_Status = new List<Cartao_Status>();               
                List<Cartao_Status> Lista_Att = new List<Cartao_Status>();                

                Lista_Status = CartoesVTBLL.Status("", "A");
                string Restricao = Lista_Status.First(x => x.Codigo == cartaoDTO.Status.Codigo).Restricao;

                Array_Restricao = Restricao.Substring(0, Restricao.Length - 1).Split(';');

                foreach (var res in Array_Restricao)
                {
                    Lista_Att.Add(Lista_Status.First(x => x.Codigo == res));
                }
                Lista_Att.Add(Lista_Status.First(x => x.Codigo == cartaoDTO.Status.Codigo));
                cboStatus.DataSource = Lista_Att;
```